# Codeigniter Sessions Database

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hi i have a user which can have multiple `site_key`.

Now When user logs in i fetch a single key from database and set session variable `site`.

Then i Have a dropdown where i show him his `site_keys`. When he selects a key from dropdown and submit that key, then session variable will be updated with the key he gave in `POST`.

i do with this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['site-list']))
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('site'); 
    $site_key =$_POST['site-list'];  
    $this->session->set_userdata('site', $site_key);
}
else
{
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('tenant_id',$id);
    $this->db->from('sites');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row(); 
    $site= $result->site_key;
    $this->session->set_userdata('site', $site);
}
```

Now my application's view depends on that session variable. So i select data to be shown as per the site key set in session.

My logic fails when i navigate to other pages. Every time the **else** will be executed.

**I want to do something like this**

Once a user logs in a key from database is set in session.

Now when he selects a key from dropdown, then only i want to update the session.

What Should I do?

Comment: This line `isset($_POST['site-list'])` is creating the issue, not every page the user visits does the post  and hence its going to else part

Comment: @Rajesh I have tried using the that but does not make much difference

Comment: i have updated my previous comment, plz check that. does every page visit post that data or what?

Comment: Okay I will try that currently offline so when I reach office will try with this

Comment: @Rajesh if i remove isset($_POST.... then what should i check in my condition ?

Comment: In the else part, add another condition to check something like this `if($this->session->userdata('site')!='')` and then execute those scripts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105071/discussion-between-rajan-and-rajesh).

Comment: Can You post ans answer based on my scenario @Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code below

```
       if (isset($_POST['site-list'])) {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('site');
        $site_key = $_POST['site-list'];
        $this->session->set_userdata('site', $site_key);
    } else {
        if ($this->session->userdata('site') != '') {
            $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where('tenant_id', $id);
            $this->db->from('sites');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->row();
            $site = $result->site_key;
            $this->session->set_userdata('site', $site);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this solves the issue but every time i refresh a page it will set the else portion site in database